# How to get data from list of lists in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get object data from a list but it does not print anything.

Here is my code:

```
 text = request.GET.get('q')
    chars = text.split()

    for tag in chars:
        brand = Brand.objects.filter(title__icontains=tag)
        if brand:
            brand_matches.append(brand)

    for brand in brand_matches:
        print brand.title
```

I am getting data in the following format:

```
[[< Brand: Athena>], [< Brand: dp>]]
```

Here each item in the list is a brand object. But I'm not able to access it.
Where am I going wrong in printing the data? Thank you.

Comment: You should add any error messages you get to your question. It makes it easier for everyone to help you.

Comment: i am not getting any error in this one...just not printing anything

Comment: I think there should be an exception since you are calling a `title()` method on a list. Lists don't have such method though.

Comment: title is a field in Brand model

Comment: I get it, but in your code you're not accessing a `Brand` model but a list that contains one `Brand` object. That's is the whole problem here and that's why your code didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `brand_matches` is a list of lists, not a list of brands.

A better way would be to have just a list of brands, not a list of lists of brands. You can achieve that like this:

```
for tag in chars:
    brand = Brand.objects.filter(title__icontains=tag)
    if brand:
        brand_matches.extend(brand)

for brand in brand_matches:
    print brand.title
```

(I used `extend()` method instead of `append()` - read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for details.)

Comment: what is [0] doing in this one?

Comment: Accessing the first item in the list of brands. But it's not the best solution. It won't work if the `filter()` method returns multiple brands for example. See the edit.

Comment: Will select_related() play a role to reduce the no of queries?